# Hibernate does another select before save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following sample code:

```
@Transactional
public void someMethod() {
    MyEntity myEntity = myRepo.findById(1).orElse(null);
    if (myEntity != null) {
        myEntity.setValue("something");
        myRepo.save(myEntity);
    }
}
```

And `myRepo` is an instance of:

```
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {}
```

So I can see the first SELECT is coming from `myRepo.findById(1)`, which makes sense. But when the code runs to `myRepo.save(myEntity)`, Hibernate somehow thinks the `myEntity` returned from `findById()` is not managed and so it does another SELECT again to create a managed entity, then replace its value using `myEntity`, then does the UPDATE.

Could you please explain why another SELECT is required and how can you avoid it? Also, the `@Transactional` annotation above the method does not change this behaviour with or without it.

Comment: Where are you calling `someMethod` from? (Also, you're actively working against `Optional`: `myRepo.findById(1).ifPresent...`)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- its called within a service, which is called by a web request.

Comment: So it's a self-call? Advice doesn't work then.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- there are quite some information in your short comment, you mean: 1. if it is not a self-call, `@Transactional` will have effect 2. `@Transactional` is exactly the thing needed to stop Hibernate from doing another SELECT before UPDATE and the `myEntity` returned from `findById()` will be managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from not very clear behavior of `@Transactional` in Spring. `@Transactional` means two things:

1. Opened persistent context (Hibernate session)
2. A transaction itself.

You have the second select because in your case `@Transactional` doesn't work at all. Hibernate opens a new persistent context for each call

1. `myRepo.findById(1)`
2. `myRepo.save(myEntity)`

if you want to do a self call, you need to pass a reference to your service to the method where you call a transactional method.

```java
class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    public void doWork(SomeService self) {
        self.someMethod();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void someMethod() {
        MyEntity myEntity = myRepo.findById(1).orElse(null);
        if (myEntity != null) {
            myEntity.setValue("something");
            myRepo.save(myEntity);
        }
    }

}
```

Example

```java
SomeService service;
service.doWork(service);
```

Another way is to autoware `self` to the service field. But it is not very good because you have to use autoware via filed injection. It is impossible to autoware using constructor. So it will be hard to do unit tests for a service.

Comment: Thanks you, so it was not the Transactional method nor Hibernate having any issue, it was how the method is called. I have resolved it by moving the method from the service to the repository (as default method).

Comment: @user1589188 When you had moved the method to the repository. You started to call the method via proxy and `@Transactional` started to work. I am not sure that the repository is a good place for it.